# SP-API GET_SALES_AND_TRAFFIC_REPORT Previous days sales timing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We use the SP API to pull sales into a dashboard for all the Amazon stores.

We used to pull the previous day at 11 am PST but its stopped working and comes in blank.

Ran the aws lambda function manually to get the Amazon Seller files to S3 (around 4PM). It did create files for 2 days before but unfortunately they were all empty for the previous day.

Does anyone know if anything changed for SP-API GET_SALES_AND_TRAFFIC_REPORT, for when the report available for the previous day?

Thanks

Ran the aws lambda function manually to get the Amazon Seller files to S3 (around 4PM). It did create files for 2 days before but unfortunately they were all empty for the previous day.